# Can I nest APC ( Alternative PHP Cache ) inside itself?

Tags: php, caching, apc

Just a quick simple question that I can not seem to find an answer for.

Can I nest APC cache inside another one?

For example, say I cache a page and I wanted it updated hourly, but I have a sidebar inside that page that I want updated every 24 hours.

Thanks!

edit: I am not asking how to do this, just if it is possible. Examples not required, unless it is a unique technique then how to normally use APC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: NO.

Long answer: you might be able to do that, but you'd have to break the page into multiple sections, and cache each section independently, and when recomposing the final page to be sent to he user grab each section from its cache...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Save the segments into separate APC variables via [`apc_store()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) and set their TTL (time to live) to 60*60 or 24*60*60, respectively.